# Comparison in empty array and null in powershell

Tags: powershell

Code:

```
$arr=@() 
if($arr -ne $null){"NE"} else{"E"} 
if($null -ne $arr){"NE"} else{"E"}
```

Output:

```
E
NE
```

How is this possible ?

Comment: The above scenario changes when you use -eq instead of -ne!  This is indeed very curious.  Please include this when considering your answers.  Result: "E", "E"

Answer (score 6):

The first `if` compares each element of the array to `$null` and produces a collection of non-null elements, which in your case is empty, thus it's false and `else` displays  `E`.

The second `if` compares a single object `$null` with another object `$arr` and since $arr itself is not `$null` (as an object that stores an empty collection inside) it displays `NE`.